# Press UIBarButtonItem programmatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I have a bar button item that I want to press programmatically, basically the equivalent of

```
buttonObj.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

but as a bar button item

edit: I forgot to mention, I can't simply call the action method for the button since I'm using the SWRevealViewController library and using their `"revealToggle:"` action on the bar button item, which I'm not sure how to call on its own.

Comment: maybe `performSelector` can help ?

Comment: @Aladin In Swift, performSelector: is not present for memory reasons

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at Objective-C equivalent questions, you'll see implementations that use `performSelector:`. In Swift, you don't have access to this method. Here's the official word on it from Apple:

> The performSelector: method and related selector-invoking methods are not imported in Swift because they are inherently unsafe.

You can solve this problem by using `UIApplication.sendAction(_:to:from:forEvent:)` instead. Technically, you should be doing this in Objective-C too.

Let's say your `UIBarButtonItem` is defined as `barButtonItem`. The following code would do what you are asking.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(barButtonItem.action, to: barButtonItem.target, from: self, forEvent: nil)
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4 (and 3) syntax

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(barButtonItem.action!, to: barButtonItem.target, from: self, for: nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

Works in **Swift 5**:

```
_ = button.target?.perform(button.action, with: nil)
```